# redirects (www, non-www, http and https) not working for sub-page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-8

I have a Laravel project and I am trying to redirect pages using .htaccess. All I want is that www, non-www and http should get redirected to https and it should work for the subpage also.
It works for the home page example.com, like, http://www, only www, only http all redirects to https.

But for the subpage, it doesn't work. like example.com/abc does not work.
for http://www and https://www, it redirects to homepage/index.php with https instead of homepage/abc

If I give only domain-name/abc or domain-name/abc with http only, abc page opens but with non-secure sign, though I have SSL installed.

Only with www prefix, it works, redirects to https://example.com/abc

Sorry, I could not write whole urls as it did not allow me to post saying possible spam.

I am using Laravel. There is a cPanel 301 Redirect record added with "Redirect with or without www", wildcard redirect is checked, domain - example.com, directory /, redirect url - https://example.com.
.htaccess is given below:

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

#redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have checked stack overflow, used .htaccess code, but they all works for home, but not working for subpages.
I have tried changing .htacces using various options but it didn't work. This is the most suitable one I could make work, at least it works for home page.

All I need is that it should redirect to https with domain-name or domain-name/abc, where 'abc' is a Laravel controller method, regardless of www, http, https or without www.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> #redirect
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

You've put the redirect rule in the wrong place. This needs to go at the top of the `.htaccess`, before your existing rules, not at the end. By placing the rule at the end of the file, any "subpages" will be redirected to `index.php` because the preceding rule internally rewrites "subpages" to the front-controller (`index.php`) first. Only once the URL has been rewritten does the redirect occur (to the rewritten URL). (Requests for the root/homepage are not rewritten by this rule.)

The order of directives in the `.htaccess` file can be important.

However, this rule checks that the `HTTP_HOST` server variable (ie. the value of the requested HTTP `Host` header) is *not* `example.com`. So naturally, it will not redirect requests for `example.com` (+HTTP) only.

Try the following instead at the *top* of the `.htaccess` file:

```
#redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This checks that either `HTTPS` is `off` *OR* the `HTTP_HOST` is not `example.com` (not the literal dot should be backslash-escaped). Note that the anchors `^` and `$` on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* are not required since regex is greedy by default.

NB: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.